# How can I send the select box value to javascript in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got the following code, which I want when people choose the OPTIONS, then show the Add an option button

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |question_form| %>
    <%= question_form.text_field :question_text %>
    <%= question_form.select :question_type, [ 'TEXT', 'OPTIONS', 'UPLOAD' ], :prompt => 'Select One', :id => "my_id", :onchange => "myFunction()" %>
    <%= question_form.link_to_remove "Remove this Question" %>
    <%= question_form.fields_for :options do |option_form| %>
        <%= option_form.text_field :option_text %>
        <%= option_form.link_to_remove "Remove this option" %>
    <% end %>
    <p id = "test" hidden><%= question_form.link_to_add "Add a option", :options %></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("my_id").value;
        if (x == "OPTIONS") {
                document.getElementById("test").hidden = false;
        }
    }
    </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This should be tagged as JavaScript more than rails

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't send a value from Rails to Js during Js execution. In that moment you are already in the browser context unless you ask something via Ajax to your server.

In this case everything can and has to be done in your browser context. Just change this line:

```
var x = document.getElementById("my_id").value
```

For:

```
var e = document.getElementById("my_id");
var x = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

This should do the trick.